# Error #2109 half the time

Tags: actionscript-3, game-engine

I'm making a platform game in AS3.

Everything is running fine except sometimes (not each time I run the game), I've got this error :

```
ArgumentError: Error #2109: Frame label null not found in scene null.
    at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
    at PlatformGame/moveCharacter()[C:\...\PlatformGame.as:581]
    at PlatformGame/moveEnemies()[C:\...\PlatformGame.as:360]
    at PlatformGame/gameLoop()[C:\...\PlatformGame.as:348]
```

I don't understand AT ALL why it happens randomly..

Do you know what could be the problem ?

Here's the lines in the error :

line 581 :

```
char.mc.gotoAndStop(char.walkAnimation[Math.floor(char.animstep)]);
```

line 360 :

```
moveCharacter(enemies[i],timeDiff);
```

line 348 :

```
moveEnemies(timeDiff);
```

Thank you for your help,

Comment: What type is animstep and how does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask to 'mc' (contained in 'char') to go to the frame which number
is contained in the array 'walkAnimation' at the index: Math.floor(char.animstep).

The error you have got means that, for some reason, 'Math.floor(char.animstep)' index doesn't exist in the array 'walkAnimation'.

Exactly as if you wrote :

```
var frame:Array = [1, 2, 3];
gotoAndStop(frame[10]);
```

frame[0] is 1, frame[1] is 2, frame[2] is 3, but frame[10] is undefined.

Comment: Quite a weak explanation since your pseudo example would generate an index range error and you claim that it will show as undefined while the PO gets a null value. undefined and null are two different value types.

Comment: @BotMaster gotoAndStop(frame[10]); // ArgumentError: Error #2109: Frame label null not found in scene null.
trace(frame[10]); // output: undefined